# MongoDB insert and update Field

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDB collection I have some fields, one of them is "EntitySet, now I need to insert a new field, for example "EntityAlchemy" to it.

This is how it looks now:

```
"EntitySet": [ 
    {
            "Name" : "maka",
            "EntityType" : "Person",
            "Relevance" : 0.0,
            "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
            "CountInText" : 0
    }
]
```

and it should look like these after the update

```
"EntitySet" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "maka",
        "EntityType" : "Person",
        "Relevance" : 0.0,
        "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
        "CountInText" : 0
    }
],
"EntityAlchemy" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "DZ Bank",
        "EntityType" : "Company",
        "Relevance" : 0.0,
        "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
        "CountInText" : 0
    }
]
```

I can only find how to update an existing field. Can someone help how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) for adding more key-value pairs.

Syntax is:

```
db.collection.update({query}, {$set: {key-value pairs}});
```

Example:

```
db.coll1.update({_id:1}, 
   {$set: "EntityAlchemy" : [ 
     {
      "Name" : "DZ Bank",
      "EntityType" : "Company",
      "Relevance" : 0.0,
      "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
      "CountInText" : 0
      }
     ]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $push for array, mongo will create the field as array if it does not exists.

```
var alchemy = {
        "Name" : "DZ Bank",
        "EntityType" : "Company",
        "Relevance" : 0.0,
        "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
        "CountInText" : 0
    };
db.getCollection('test').update({_id:1},{$push : {'EntityAlchemy' : alchemy}});
```

Comment: I know how to do this in the mongo shell, my problem is I have to do it in java and I can't make it work.

Comment: In java also it can be done, which driver you are using? Spring-data you can use Update command

Comment: I found out how to insert the field into java now. But I also need to insert the new field in all of my records so every record has another Array. ie  record 1 "EntityAlchemy" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "DZ Bank",
        "EntityType" : "Company",
        "Relevance" : 0.0,
        "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
        "CountInText" : 0
    } and then record 2 "EntityAlchemy" : [ 
    {
        "Name" : "DZ",
        "EntityType" : "whatever",
        "Relevance" : 1.0,
        "SentimentScore" : 0.0,
        "CountInText" : 0
    } is it possible to insert different ones at one time?

Comment: Different document can be updated for a field with same value but not for different value, so answer is no you can't add different values in different document by same update command